# Terraform compliance: how do i check that my GCP resources have a label with a given key?

Tags: terraform

I have just discovered [terraform compliance](https://terraform-compliance.com/pages/bdd-references/when.html) and am testing it out against my terraform code that deploys resources to GCP.

GCP labels enable fine-grained cost analysis and every labels attribute is a map ([bigquery_dataset#labels](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_dataset#labels)) so I would like to verify that every resource that has a `labels` argument includes a certain key that we use for analysing costs. Here is an example terraform configuration:

```
variable "project"{
 type = string
}

provider "google" {
  region = "europe-west2"
}

resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "dataset1" {
  dataset_id    = "dataset1"
  project       = var.project
  labels        = { "label1" : "some_value" }
}

resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "dataset2" {
  dataset_id    = "dataset2"
  project       = var.project
  labels        = { "anotherlabel" : "some_value" }
}

resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "dataset3" {
  dataset_id    = "dataset3"
  project       = var.project
}
```

dataset3 is not acceptable because it doesn't have any labels. dataset2 is unacceptable because while it does have labels, it doesn't have the one I want it to  have, `label1`

I would like to use terraform compliance to check for these anomolies but I can't figure out how. here is my feature file, `test.feature`:

```
Feature: Terraform Compliance

Scenario: My scenario
    Given I have any resource defined
    When it has labels
    Then it must contain label1
```

I then issue :

```sh
terraform init ^^ \
  terraform plan --var=project=myproject --out=plan.out && \
  terraform-compliance --planfile plan.out -f .
```

which produces this output:

> terraform-compliance v1.3.24 initiated
>
> . Converting terraform plan file.
>  Features     : /tmp/tctest/
>  Plan File    : /tmp/tctest/plan.out.json
>
> Running tests.
>
> Feature: Terraform Compliance  # /tmp/terraformcompliancetest/test.feature
>
> ```
> Scenario: My scenario
>     Given I have any resource defined
>     When it has labels
>             Failure: google_bigquery_dataset.dataset2 (google_bigquery_dataset) does not have label1 property.
>             Failure: google_bigquery_dataset.dataset3 (google_bigquery_dataset) does not have label1 property.
>     Then it must contain label1
>       Failure:
> ```
>
> 1 features (0 passed, 1 failed)
> 1 scenarios (0 passed, 1 failed)
> 3 steps (2 passed, 1 failed)
> Run 1629659085 finished within a moment

Clearly this isn't giving me what I want. I've pored over the docs but can't figure out what I'm supposed to be putting in my feature file. Can anyone help?

---

UPDATE As [requested on twitter](https://twitter.com/terraformtest/status/1429524432830222343?s=20), here is the contents of plan.out.json

```json
{
    "format_version": "0.1",
    "terraform_version": "0.14.7",
    "variables": {
        "project": {
            "value": "myproject"
        }
    },
    "planned_values": {
        "root_module": {
            "resources": [
                {
                    "address": "google_bigquery_dataset.dataset1",
                    "mode": "managed",
                    "type": "google_bigquery_dataset",
                    "name": "dataset1",
                    "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google",
                    "schema_version": 0,
                    "values": {
                        "dataset_id": "dataset1",
                        "default_encryption_configuration": [],
                        "default_partition_expiration_ms": null,
                        "default_table_expiration_ms": null,
                        "delete_contents_on_destroy": false,
                        "description": null,
                        "friendly_name": null,
                        "labels": {
                            "label1": "some_value"
                        },
                        "location": "US",
                        "project": "myproject",
                        "timeouts": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "address": "google_bigquery_dataset.dataset2",
                    "mode": "managed",
                    "type": "google_bigquery_dataset",
                    "name": "dataset2",
                    "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google",
                    "schema_version": 0,
                    "values": {
                        "dataset_id": "dataset2",
                        "default_encryption_configuration": [],
                        "default_partition_expiration_ms": null,
                        "default_table_expiration_ms": null,
                        "delete_contents_on_destroy": false,
                        "description": null,
                        "friendly_name": null,
                        "labels": {
                            "anotherlabel": "some_value"
                        },
                        "location": "US",
                        "project": "myproject",
                        "timeouts": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "address": "google_bigquery_dataset.dataset3",
                    "mode": "managed",
                    "type": "google_bigquery_dataset",
                    "name": "dataset3",
                    "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google",
                    "schema_version": 0,
                    "values": {
                        "dataset_id": "dataset3",
                        "default_encryption_configuration": [],
                        "default_partition_expiration_ms": null,
                        "default_table_expiration_ms": null,
                        "delete_contents_on_destroy": false,
                        "description": null,
                        "friendly_name": null,
                        "labels": null,
                        "location": "US",
                        "project": "myproject",
                        "timeouts": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "resource_changes": [
        {
            "address": "google_bigquery_dataset.dataset1",
            "mode": "managed",
            "type": "google_bigquery_dataset",
            "name": "dataset1",
            "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google",
            "change": {
                "actions": [
                    "create"
                ],
                "before": null,
                "after": {
                    "dataset_id": "dataset1",
                    "default_encryption_configuration": [],
                    "default_partition_expiration_ms": null,
                    "default_table_expiration_ms": null,
                    "delete_contents_on_destroy": false,
                    "description": null,
                    "friendly_name": null,
                    "labels": {
                        "label1": "some_value"
                    },
                    "location": "US",
                    "project": "myproject",
                    "timeouts": null
                },
                "after_unknown": {
                    "access": true,
                    "creation_time": true,
                    "default_encryption_configuration": [],
                    "etag": true,
                    "id": true,
                    "labels": {},
                    "last_modified_time": true,
                    "self_link": true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "address": "google_bigquery_dataset.dataset2",
            "mode": "managed",
            "type": "google_bigquery_dataset",
            "name": "dataset2",
            "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google",
            "change": {
                "actions": [
                    "create"
                ],
                "before": null,
                "after": {
                    "dataset_id": "dataset2",
                    "default_encryption_configuration": [],
                    "default_partition_expiration_ms": null,
                    "default_table_expiration_ms": null,
                    "delete_contents_on_destroy": false,
                    "description": null,
                    "friendly_name": null,
                    "labels": {
                        "anotherlabel": "some_value"
                    },
                    "location": "US",
                    "project": "myproject",
                    "timeouts": null
                },
                "after_unknown": {
                    "access": true,
                    "creation_time": true,
                    "default_encryption_configuration": [],
                    "etag": true,
                    "id": true,
                    "labels": {},
                    "last_modified_time": true,
                    "self_link": true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "address": "google_bigquery_dataset.dataset3",
            "mode": "managed",
            "type": "google_bigquery_dataset",
            "name": "dataset3",
            "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google",
            "change": {
                "actions": [
                    "create"
                ],
                "before": null,
                "after": {
                    "dataset_id": "dataset3",
                    "default_encryption_configuration": [],
                    "default_partition_expiration_ms": null,
                    "default_table_expiration_ms": null,
                    "delete_contents_on_destroy": false,
                    "description": null,
                    "friendly_name": null,
                    "labels": null,
                    "location": "US",
                    "project": "myproject",
                    "timeouts": null
                },
                "after_unknown": {
                    "access": true,
                    "creation_time": true,
                    "default_encryption_configuration": [],
                    "etag": true,
                    "id": true,
                    "last_modified_time": true,
                    "self_link": true
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "configuration": {
        "provider_config": {
            "google": {
                "name": "google",
                "expressions": {
                    "region": {
                        "constant_value": "europe-west2"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "root_module": {
            "resources": [
                {
                    "address": "google_bigquery_dataset.dataset1",
                    "mode": "managed",
                    "type": "google_bigquery_dataset",
                    "name": "dataset1",
                    "provider_config_key": "google",
                    "expressions": {
                        "dataset_id": {
                            "constant_value": "dataset1"
                        },
                        "labels": {
                            "constant_value": {
                                "label1": "some_value"
                            }
                        },
                        "project": {
                            "references": [
                                "var.project"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "schema_version": 0
                },
                {
                    "address": "google_bigquery_dataset.dataset2",
                    "mode": "managed",
                    "type": "google_bigquery_dataset",
                    "name": "dataset2",
                    "provider_config_key": "google",
                    "expressions": {
                        "dataset_id": {
                            "constant_value": "dataset2"
                        },
                        "labels": {
                            "constant_value": {
                                "anotherlabel": "some_value"
                            }
                        },
                        "project": {
                            "references": [
                                "var.project"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "schema_version": 0
                },
                {
                    "address": "google_bigquery_dataset.dataset3",
                    "mode": "managed",
                    "type": "google_bigquery_dataset",
                    "name": "dataset3",
                    "provider_config_key": "google",
                    "expressions": {
                        "dataset_id": {
                            "constant_value": "dataset3"
                        },
                        "project": {
                            "references": [
                                "var.project"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "schema_version": 0
                }
            ],
            "variables": {
                "project": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing it from mobile, so didnt try thoroughly.

Can you please try ?

```
Scenario: My scenario
    Given I have any resource defined
    When it has labels
    Then it must have labels
    Then it must contain label1
```

As you see the fix is adding a “then” after “when” because all “When” directives are for filtering while “Then” directives drills down the resource data.

Hope it fixes :)

//Edit:
Here is the output I got ;

```
 Running tests. 

Feature: test  

    Scenario: My scenario
        Given I have any resource defined
        When it has labels
        Then it must have labels
        Failure: google_bigquery_dataset.dataset2 (any resource) does not have label1 property.
        Failure: google_bigquery_dataset.dataset3 (any resource) does not have label1 property.
        Then it must have label1
          Failure:

1 features (0 passed, 1 failed)
1 scenarios (0 passed, 1 failed)
4 steps (3 passed, 1 failed)
```

Comment: Hi, really appreciate the reply. That returned an error: `❗ ERROR: There is no step defintion for 'Then it has labels'.. Looks like a syntax error.` (typo on "defintion" isn't mine :) )

Comment: oh sorry, fixing the post. Writing from mobile has problems :D

Comment: yep sounds like it gives the output you wanted. Posting the result to the post as well,.

Comment: Seen your edit, that *almost* gives me what I want :) I expected dataset3 to fail because it didn't have any value specified for label. it *is* failing, but not for the correct reason.

Comment: Ah, I wonder if the reason that it didn;t complain about dataset3 not having labels is that even though the tf code doesn;t define anything for labels in plan.out.json I can see `"labels": null`. So the question becomes, how do i check that something isn't null

Comment: With this : https://terraform-compliance.com/pages/bdd-references/then.html#then-its-value-condition-be-null :)

Comment: Instead of doing this, you can also start your Scenario with `Given I have resource that supports labels defined`

Comment: I marked your response as an answer and also posted a response of my own which built on what you provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Had loads of help from @emre-erkunt and his reply almost gave me what I need (and will make that reply as an answer). I modified it slightly to include two scenarios:

```
Feature: Terraform Compliance

Scenario: Labels must be defined
    Given I have resource that supports labels defined
    When it has labels
    Then it must have labels
    Then its value must not be null

Scenario: Labels must include label1
    Given I have resource that supports labels defined
    When it has labels
    Then it must have labels
    Then it must have label1
```

Which returns:

> terraform-compliance v1.3.24 initiated
>
> . Converting terraform plan file.
>  Features     : /tmp/tctest/
>  Plan File    : /tmp/tctest/plan.out.json
>
> Running tests.
>
> Feature: Terraform Compliance  # /tmp/tctest/test.feature
>
> ```
> Scenario: Labels must be defined  
>     Given I have resource that supports labels defined  
>     When it has labels  
>     Then it must have labels  
>             Failure: labels property in google_bigquery_dataset.dataset3 is considered to be Null. It is set to None.  
>     Then its value must not be null  
>       Failure:  
>
> Scenario: Labels must include label1  
>     Given I have resource that supports labels defined  
>     When it has labels  
>     Then it must have labels  
>             Failure: google_bigquery_dataset.dataset2 (resource that supports labels) does not have label1 property.  
>             Failure: google_bigquery_dataset.dataset3 (resource that supports labels) does not have label1 property.  
>     Then it must have label1  
>       Failure:
> ```
>
> 1 features (0 passed, 1 failed)
> 2 scenarios (0 passed, 2 failed)
> 8 steps (6 passed, 2 failed)
> Run 1629663083 finished within a moment

which is satisfactory and I think as close as I'm going to get to exactly what I want.

Massive thank you to Emre.